# Use comma in path in karate test

Tags: karate

With the following test case

```
Background:
    * callonce read('auth.feature')
    * url java.lang.System.getenv('TEST_URL')

Scenario: Call the file endpoint without authorization

    Given path 'files/123695_11,8'
    When method get
    Then status 401
```

I get a parser error about mismatching quotes. The reason is probably that the "path" is confused by the comma, as that can also be used to denote sub-paths.

I thought about just changing the `,` to `%2C`, but then karate calls the URL with the `%` encoded to `%25`, resulting in a wrong URL `'files/123695_11%252C8'` which decodes to literally `'files/123695_11%2C8'`.

How can I make this work correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest option, merge into `url`:

```
* url 'https://httpbin.org/anything/files/123695_11,8'
* method get
```

I know you may want to "re-use" stuff in the background, so use variables:

```
Background:
* def baseUrl = 'https://httpbin.org/anything'

Scenario: 
* url baseUrl + '/files/123695_11,8'
* method get
```

Hacky workaround:

```
* url 'https://httpbin.org/anything'
* def temp = 'files/123695_11,8'
* path temp
* method get
```

Comment: Using `baseUrl` variable is perfect, because we're already pulling that from the environment, so I just need to adjust the scenarios. Thanks!